# MVC Javascript Show UTC Clock using setTimeOut function

Tags: jquery

I want to implement JavaScript Clock which shown only UTC time. It will not change if user change his Computer.

http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc

Like this.

```
setInterval(function () {
   console.log(new Date('@DateTime.UtcNow'));
}, 1000);
```

Why this is not showing server time every second. I just want to create a notification when UTC time is Today 10 AM, it will popup the user. How to do this on client side. It will not affect the popup if user change the system time of his computer.

Please let me know if any more discussion required.

Comment: I think you need to use server time for starting, after use countdown controller in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you take date from server side means controller side(@DateTime.UtcNow) used in java script so its is fixed on all the request so it is prompt same time all the interval request.

Below example will be used in your case.

```
<span id="txttime" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            var dt = new Date();
            $("#txttime").text(("" + dt.getUTCMonth() + "/" + dt.getUTCDay() + "/" + dt.getUTCFullYear() + " " + dt.getUTCHours() + ":" + dt.getUTCMinutes() + " " + dt.getUTCSeconds() + "") + ' UTC Time');
            if(dt.getUTCHours() == 10)
            {
                alert("Prompt window when 10AM from UTC time");
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
```